# Upload files into buddypress profiles

Tags: buddypress

Someone knows any plugin or method to allow users to upload files into their profiles? I mean i can link those files later to their profiles is the files are linked to users some way.
I want to allow my users to upload papers, pdf , etc and then show those files on their profiles.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found  this great plugin called "Uploadify Integration" by Mike Allen that did the trick.